Appropriate statistical significance test for categorical independent variables with binary dependent variable
I am trying to determine whether a language prediction model predicts significantly more accurate sentiment values than other language prediction models.
There are three language prediction models that I am trying to predict: English, French, and other.
Below is a dummy data to replicate my research:
set.seed(123)

#n languages
n_english <- 123
n_french <- 180
n_other <- 52

#unique id
df <- data.frame(id = 1:(n_english + n_french + n_other))

#assign languages to df#lang
df$lang <- c(rep("English", n_english), rep("French", n_french), rep("Other", n_other))

#generate random values
df$accuracy <- NA
df$accuracy[df$lang == "English"] <- rbinom(n_english, 1, prob = 0.87)
df$accuracy[df$lang == "French"] <- rbinom(n_french, 1, prob = 0.75)
df$accuracy[df$lang == "Other"] <- rbinom(n_other, 1, prob = 0.90)

tibble(df)
# A tibble: 355 × 3
      id lang    accuracy
   <int> <chr>      <int>
 1     1 English        1
 2     2 English        1
 3     3 English        1
 4     4 English        0
 5     5 English        0
 6     6 English        1
 7     7 English        1
 8     8 English        0
 9     9 English        1
10    10 English        1
# ℹ 345 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

hist(df$accuracy)

The dataframe indicates that language variables have Bernoulli distribution, therefore not satisfying the criteria for a parametric test. What appropriate test statistics should I use to determine whether there is significant outcome of accurate prediction between the languages?
Below is the code where I tried to visualize the data using boxplot to get a sense of the difference of mean of accuracy of each languages:
df %>%
  group_by(lang) %>%
  summarize(
    mean = mean(accuracy),
    sd = sd(accuracy)
  ) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = lang)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(lower=mean-sd,upper=mean+sd,middle=mean,ymin=mean-0*sd,ymax=mean+0*sd),stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "lang", y = "accuracy") +
  theme_bw()


I want the test statistics to show significance in terms of the difference of means of accurate prediction each variable.
Every answers to similar questions I have read in various forums had suggested me to conduct a logistic regression; however, I am not trying to make a regression model that determine the probability of a binary outcome given an event.
Thank you!

Need some more context: what is the id column? It seems like you have a number of cases of sentiments? phrases? and for each you have the language (model?) and a binary variable 0 = not accurate, 1 = accurate? If so, you can either use a Chi-Square of the counts of accurate and non accurate cases by language, or fit a logistic regression and get comparisons between languages based on how you code your language variable in the model
